# Local users and Domain user on windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a VOIP soft phone that requires users personal machines be on the domain for it to work reliably. We have a local user account setup for his wife but is there any way to get it to list as a logon option along side the "domain account" and "switch user" buttons?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is by design. Once a computer is on the domain, you will need to use the "Other User" button under "Switch User". Once there, she can type in ".\username" then her password. The "." is a replacement for localhost when logging in locally.

Comment: I know its a design 'feature' but no ones been able to find away around it?

Comment: Remove it from the domain

Comment: Then the phone wont work right...